# How to handle paths to files with extra parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, path

I'm downloading files from the Internet inside of my application. Now I'm dealing with multiple file types so I need to able to detect what file type the file is before my application can continue. The problem that I ran into is that some of the URLs where the files are getting downloaded from contain extra parameters.

For example:

```
http://www.myfaketestsite.com/myaudio.mp3?id=20
```

Originally I was using `String.EndsWith()`. Obviously this doesn't work anymore. Any idea on how to detect the file type?

Comment: An alternative to parsing might be Response.ContentType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the URL in a `Uri` class. It will split it up into different segments that you can use, or you can use the helper methods on the `Uri` class itself:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.myfaketestsite.com/myaudio.mp3?id=20");
string path = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
// path = "http://www.myfaketestsite.com/myaudio.mp3"
```

Your question is a duplicate of:

- [Truncating Query String & Returning Clean URL C# ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188096/truncating-query-string-returning-clean-url-c-asp-net/1188180#1188180)
- [Get url without querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630249/get-url-without-querystring)

Comment: What method should I use to accomplish this. Do I get the Query property and remove it from the original path?

Comment: @loyalpenguin: If you use the code above, the `path` variable will contain `http://www.myfaketestsite.com/myaudio.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always split on the question mark to eliminate the parameters. e.g.

```
string s = "http://www.myfaketestsite.com/myaudio.mp3?id=20";
string withoutQueryString = s.Split('?')[0];
```

If no question mark exists, it won't matter, as you'll still be grabbing the value from the zero index.  You can then do your logic on the `withoutQueryString` string.